# What is the word for a widely shared understanding that is counter to scientific analysis?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

In a discussion with a friend he noted that the colour magenta is not a real colour. I have also heard of this and you can read more on that [on Mentalfloss](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/91138/how-see-colors-dont-exist).

I would like to know if a word or phrase exists to express the mass agreement of people which runs counter to scientific analysis or technical correctness. Yes, magenta is not a real wave length but I can reach an understanding with a layman on what magenta is.

Comment: Yellow isn't a wavelength either, but a name applied to a perceived range of colors, just as magenta is. Magenta is a color.

Comment: Also, color names can also be used to distinguish intensity: brown is simply a dark orange.  The same color can appear brown or orange depending on the background. // There are also [impossible colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impossible_color)

Comment: The colour example involves semantics. The stipulative, wavelength-based definition used in physics cuts across the subjective, 'appearance- (to a normally sighted person ... or even perhaps not) based' (see Collins) definition. Anyone claiming 'X is not a colour' (X a reasonable candidate) without first defining terms is being unscholarly. // The question itself would be on-topic had it not been answered before ('folk physics' being a new hyponymic, though perhaps here more accurate, answer).

Comment: The duplicate question is unrelated. This question expresses a shared understanding and the ability to communicate in relation to a subjective understanding which runs counter to the scientific understanding of the world. The question marked as duplicate expresses a false belief.

Answer (score 0):

*Folk* is the term used for naive  understanding in different fields of study, e.g.,  *folk etymology* and *folk philosophy*.

> **folk**   (adj.)
>
> Of or relating to the common people or to the study of the common people
>
> *folk sociology* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/folk)

**Folk Physics / Naïve Physics**

> **Folk Physics**
>
> A term for people spontaneously understanding the workings of the
> physical world. Contrary to scientific physics, **folk physics** is based
> on immediate human understanding of the nature of physical objects and
> intuitive human prediction of physical events in nature. It can be
> seen as a naïve or common sense approach to human environment. Human
> interaction with the physical environment is normally based on habits
> and practical understanding that are very different from the
> theoretical approach of scientific physics. Thus, insights gained by
> folk physics are often characterized as contrary to those of
> scientific physics, and are therefore deemed wrong and misleading with
> respect to a scientific understanding of the physical world. [A. Runehov and L. Oviedo (eds.) *Encyclopedia of Sciences and Religion*](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-1-4020-8265-8_200274)

> **Naïve physics or folk physics** is the untrained human perception of
> basic physical phenomena. In the field of artificial intelligence the
> study of naïve physics is a part of the effort to formalize the common
> knowledge of human beings.
>
> *Many ideas of **folk physics** are simplifications, misunderstandings, or
> misperceptions of well-understood phenomena, incapable of giving
> useful predictions of detailed experiments, or simply are contradicted
> by more thorough observations. **They may sometimes be true, be true in
> certain limited cases, be true as a good first approximation to a more
> complex effect, or predict the same effect but misunderstand the
> underlying mechanism.***
>
> **Naïve physics** can also be defined as an intuitive understanding all
> humans have about objects in the physical world. Certain notions of
> the physical world may be innate. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Na%C3%AFve_physics)

> [J. Peter and J. Garvin; ***Folk Physics**, Pre-science, and Demarcations
> of Science*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Folk_Physics_Pre_science_and_Demarcation/xKvQvQEACAAJ?hl=en) (2017)

Of course magenta is "real" in that it's perceived as a color, regardless of the mechanism.

Comment: There's also [Cartoon Physics](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~karan/courses/csc2529/cartoonlaw.htm), like that found in Roadrunner cartoons.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't buy anything from ACME.

Answer (score 0):

If context is about an event or occurrence, **urban myth** would be a good fit.

> - The phrase **urban myth** – is quite new. Curiously, an urban myth does not usually have anything to do with the city: it is simply “a story about an unusual event or occurrence that many people believe is true but that is not true.” An example would be the tale that Elvis Presley is still alive after spending decades in a witness protection program. The phrase urban myth has been used to describe such hoaxes since at least 1971. [**MW**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/myth) see also "urban legend"

"legend" and "myth" also convey "mass agreement of people" but not necessarily  "which runs counter to scientific analysis or technical correctness."

Answer (score -2):

This may be slightly off the mark of what you're looking for, but there's the well-publicized "[Mandela Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_memory#Manifestations_and_types)", a category of "false memory," in which a mass opinion is not merely slightly inaccurate but fully convinced of something patently false, especially as regards the record of their memories.